# Lista encadeada(linked list) populada com strings

Tags: c, estrutura-de-dados, lista-encadeada

Olá, estou tentando criar uma lista que seja populada com strings porém quando tento imprimi-lá não aparece nada. Agradeço qualquer ajuda disponível.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>

typedef struct tipoNo {
    char* info;
    struct tipoNo *prox;    
} no;

void iniLista(no **L) {
    *L = NULL;
}

void print(no **L) {
    no *P;
    P = *L;

    while(P != NULL) {
        printf("%c", P->info);
        P = P->prox;
    }
}
//insere        
void push(no **L, char* x) {
    no *P, *N;

    N = (no *) malloc (sizeof(no));
    N->info = x;

    if(*L == NULL) {
        *L = N;
    }
    else {
        P = *L;

        while(P->prox != NULL) {
            P = P->prox;
        }
        P->prox = N;
    }
    N->prox = NULL;
}

int main() {
    no *L;

    push(&L, "asasas");
    push(&L, "basasa");
    print(&L);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Estude com atenção o que resultará de: `N->info = x;` dentro da função push.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esse é um nó de sua lista:

```
typedef struct tipoNo 
{
    char*           info;
    struct tipoNo*  prox;

}   no;
```

E não devia ser sua lista. Uma lista ligada é uma coleção de nós e não um nó. Toda vez que você usar um **node** como se fosse uma lista vai ter mais trabalho e menos resultado. A estrutura tem *metadados*, coisas para manter a lista funcionando. Se controlar isso fora dela fica difícil e inseguro. Imagine se tiver várias dessas listas no mesmo programa por exemplo: Como vai controlar as variáveis que se referem a cada lista?

Compare com algo assim

```
struct a_propria_lista
{
    char*     nome;
    unsigned  quantos;
    unsigned  maximo;
    Node*     inicio;
    Node*     fim;
};
typedef struct a_propria_lista Lista;
```

E entenda que cada coisa declarada

```
    Lista    lista;
    Lista*   coisas[4];
```

como `Lista` tem seu próprio tamanho, limites e ponteiros. E vai tudo junto na declaração., Muito mais cômodo. É o lance do encapsulamento. E você pode usar ou não todos os campos, pode criar novos campos sem mexer nos argumentos, e a vida segue. Considere isso.

#### De volta ao seu programa

Outro problema é a alocação de memória: não pode simplesmente escrever

```
    N->info = x;
```

tendo declarado

```
    void push(no **L, char* x);
```

e usando

```
    no *L;
    push(&L, "asasas");
    push(&L, "asasas"); // sim, o mesmo
    push(&L, "asasas"); // e de novo
```

Como eu disse acima, `no` é um nó e não uma lista. E devia ter sido inicializado. Mas o problema mesmo é que "asasas" não é exatamente `char*`. Você deve copiar os dados para a área alocada e não copiar o ponteiro. Imagine por exemplo se `push()` é chamada de dentro de uma outra função.

- ao retornar da função todas as variáveis da função deixam de existir. Como fica sua lista?
- um literal *"asasas"* é `const char[7]`. Imagine como ficaria seu programa ao tentar remover algum deles da lista
- essas constantes podem ser otimizadas pelo compilador, já que são constantes e tem o mesmo valor, e aí vai ter elementos na lista apontando para o mesmo endereço
- qualquer dessas razões serviria para cancelar seu programa
- strings em C são null-terminated então você tem que reservar uma posição também para o terminador da string, o zero no final
- use `main()` **SEMPRE** como a primeira função de seu programa. É melhor para você e para quem quer que vá ler seu programa...
- use `const char*` em casos como esse em que pode ser que a função seja chamada com um argumento constante, assim você se protege desse tipo de erro
- evite usar void. Em geral é um desperdício e muitas vezes é um erro mesmo. Quase sempre tem algo útil para retornar. Nesses casos de Lista por exemplo pode retornar o ponteiro para o início da lista ao invés de passar sempre `no**`. Vou mostrar um exemplo numa hipotética função `apaga()`

#### Como fez ainda funciona, só dá mais trabalho

Um exemplo de push() que funcionaria

```
void push(no** L, const char* x)
{
    no* novo = (no*)malloc(sizeof(no));
    // aloca a string do tamanho certo
    novo->prox = NULL;
    novo->info = (char*)malloc(1 + strlen(x));
    // copia os dados nao o ponteiro
    strcpy(novo->info, x);
    // push(): essa versao insere novos elementos
    // no final da lista
    if (*L == NULL)
    {
        *L = novo;
        return;
    };
    no* p = *L;
    while (p->prox != NULL)
        p = p->prox;
    p->prox = novo;
    return;
```

#### um programa de teste

Esse programa cria esses dois elementos que usava e depois mais alguns usando `sprintf()` para numerar uma string

```
int main(void)
{
    char string[20];
    no* L = NULL;

    push(&L, "asasas");
    push(&L, "basasa");
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i += 1)
    {
        sprintf(string, "Teste %02d", i);
        push(&L, string);
    };  // for()
    print(&L);

    // apaga tudo
    L = apaga(L);

    return 0;
};  // main()
```

#### saída

```
asasas
basasa
Teste 01
Teste 02
Teste 03
Teste 04
Teste 05
Teste 06
Teste 07
Teste 08
Teste 09
Lista apagada
```

#### o programa todo

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct tipoNo 
{
    char*           info;
    struct tipoNo*  prox;

}   no;

no*     apaga(no*);
void    iniLista(no**);
void    print(no**);
void    push(no**, const char* x);

int main(void)
{
    char string[20];
    no* L = NULL;

    push(&L, "asasas");
    push(&L, "basasa");
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i += 1)
    {
        sprintf(string, "Teste %02d", i);
        push(&L, string);
    };  // for()
    print(&L);

    // apaga tudo
    L = apaga(L);

    return 0;
};  // main()

no* apaga(no* lista)
{
    // apaga as strings primeiro
    if (lista == NULL) return NULL;
    no* p = NULL;
    do
    {
        p = lista->prox; // salva esse
        free(lista);
        lista = p;

    } while (p->prox != NULL);
    printf("Lista apagada\n");
    return NULL;
}

void iniLista(no** L) { *L = NULL; }

void print(no** L)
{
    no* p = *L;
    while (p != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s\n", p->info);
        p = p->prox;
    }
};  // print()

void push(no** L, const char* x)
{
    no* novo = (no*)malloc(sizeof(no));
    // aloca a string do tamanho certo
    novo->prox = NULL;
    novo->info = (char*)malloc(1 + strlen(x));
    // copia os dados nao o ponteiro
    strcpy(novo->info, x);
    // push(): essa versao insere novos elementos
    // no final da lista
    if (*L == NULL)
    {
        *L = novo;
        return;
    };
    no* p = *L;
    while (p->prox != NULL)
        p = p->prox;
    p->prox = novo;
    return;

};  // push()
```

Comment: rapaz, tu foi um anjo agora! O que tu disse do N->info = x; estava comprometendo todo o meu código onde implemento esta lista, o seu programa realmente me salvou, muito obrigado

Comment: Bom que funcionou. Quando tiver um tempo atente para aquelas outras coisas que eu listei, como o lance do byte a mais, o caso de retornar o endereço como em `apaga()` e a estrutura separada para `Lista`, os protótipos para as funções no início do programa

Answer (score 0):

O problema é relativamente óbvio e observável.

```
while(P != NULL) {
        printf("%c", P->info);
        P = P->prox;
```

Preste atenção ao printf e o parametro que lhe passa.
A estrutura tem como valor definido um ponteiro para char (string), mas a função print só está a imprimir um caractere.

**Mude de "%c" para "%s".**

Comment: Era exatamente isso aí e também não estava iniciando a lista no main. Muito obrigado!

Comment: Tem mais problemas. Recomendo ler o que eu escrevi e comparar com o exemplo que deixei no post